Slope of the tangent line of the sine graph at x = 60 degrees.
f(x) = sin(x) is a sine function where x is in degree measure. What is the slope of the tangent line when x = 60 degrees?
Some says 0.5, and some says ($\pi$/90). Which is correct?

What is the definition of the tangent of an angle?

Let $\sin_d(x) = \sin(x°) = f(x)$ and $\cos_d(x) = \cos(x°)$, to distinguish them from the “normal” trig functions that use radians.  Then:
$$\sin_d(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi x}{180})$$
Differentiate by using the chain rule.
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \sin_d(x) = \frac{\pi}{180}\cos(\frac{\pi x}{180})$$
Just plug in $x = 60$ to get:
$$f'(60) = \frac{\pi}{180}\cos(\frac{ 60 \pi}{180}) = \frac{\pi}{180}\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\pi}{180}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\pi}{360}$$
BTW, this is a big reason why calculus prefers to define $\sin$ and $\cos$ in radians: That way, you just have $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \cos(x)$ and $\frac{d}{dx} \cos(x) = -\sin(x)$, without the awkward constant factor that you'd introduce for any other unit of angle.
